Mustard fields around Berlin with 49 euro ticket
Are there any Mustard fields around Berlin? Ideally somewhere I could visit with the 49 euro ticket for a day trip?

You might ask these guys: https://klosterfelder-senfmuehle.de/pages/handler

Google Maps might give you some ideas where to look - yellow fields are either rapeseed or mustard.

I foud a map of crop types in Germany, but unfortunately "mustard" is not one of the categories.

Born Senf sources its mustard seed from Großvargula in Thüringen. From the photo on the linked page, I would look for the fields on the south side of the village, with a view onto the wind farm to the north west. Or give the farmer a call!
If you only want to use the Deutschlandticket, it's a journey of 6:30h from Berlin Hbf, so that's not really feasible for a day trip. If you allow for an ICE journey between Berlin and Erfurt, it goes down to just above 3 hours, making it doable.
There are also mustard fields in the Oberlausitz, near Bautzen, that Bautz'ner Senf sources from, some apparently in the immediate vicinity of Kleinwelka, but I don't know an exact location. Bautzen itself is reachable within 3:37h in regional trains from Berlin Hbf.
